# Scala and Play framework Web Application hosting

Tags: scala, playframework, hosting

I`m looking for a hosting package for scala and play  in Amazon elastic servers. If there is anybody here is done it before? what are the ideal solution for a small ERP application?

Answer (score 2):

you can easily deploy playframework web application on elastic beanstalk using docker container.

1. Create environment on EBS using docker container.
2. package your app using sbt docker:stage
3. make a zip of target/docker/stage/*
4. deploy this zip on EBS environment.

you can explore docker @ https://www.docker.com/

Comment: I got error while execute the **sbt docker:stage** command. here  [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38371993/scala-web-application-hosting-in-amazon-elastic-beanstalk)